# How to create multi store module in the Magento

Tags: magento

I want to create my custom module multi store compatible. I want to get the value from my custom database table as per configuration scope. While adding the values to the database table, i have specified the scope_id and scope like as Magento does in the core_config_data table. Now how can i fetch those inserted value from the table according to the selected website on the front end.

I have the following database value snippet.

ID    value   scope_id    scope

1    test       0         default
2    test1    4          store 
3    test12   5          website

Can anybody help me in this?  Thanks

Comment: I suggest you to use the system.xml file to specify new configuration params with a store scope instead of inserting direct values. Then it's easy to get the good config param from core_config_data table

Comment: Are you want to display store multiselect dropdown in you module form or i misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so easy to reuse Magento's config loading for your own needs.

What you want is to inherit your values from default -> website -> store (if not overwritten in there).

Magento converts the database config to the internal XML representation in `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Config::loadToXml` and does the merging and inheritance logic in there.

The inheritance logic is all in the `loadToXml()` function - so you could implement something similar if you want to take the same approach and build your values for each store scope.

If you simply need to get one value for a specific scope you just have to read the database row with that store, if not found with the website the store is in, if not found the default value.

Comment: Can you give me some suggestion that how can i do this in my custom module?